# UICollectionView in UITableView doesn't detect tap because of view.addGestureRecognizer()

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

I have UITableView with embedded UICollectionView. In the first section there are custom cells with UITextField and in the second one there is UICollectionView.

To hide a keyboard when a user taps outside of UITextField I am using

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

func dismissKeyboard(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Because of it, as I have figured out, my UICollectionView doesn't recognize taps on its items. If I remove **view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)** Everything works fine, but keyboard doesn't hide in this case.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()  //if desired
    return true
} 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProfileTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ProfileTableViewCell

        cell.value.delegate = self // value is my textField
        return cell

    case 1:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WallpaperTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! WallpaperTableViewCell
            cell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: self, index: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row)
        return cell

    default:
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        return cell
    }
}
```

How can fix this issue and use together hiding keyboard and tap recognition in UICollectionView?
Thanks

To embed UICollectionView in UITableView I have used this example https://github.com/DahanHu/DHCollectionTableView

**UPD**

Thanks to Phillip Mills

The answer was pretty easiest

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

and

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    view.removeGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your gesture recognizer only when the keyboard appears and remove it when you dismiss the keyboard.